# Huffman Encoding - how do I reference to the node in the top of the huffman tree ?

Tags: java, tree, huffman-code

This program should take a file and compress it with the huffman code. My problem is that I have to have `Element X` to reference to the top of the huffman tree, in my `Coder` method:

```
     public static String Coder(Element Z){
        Element X = Z;
        if(Z != null){
            Coder(Z.left);
            if(Z.isleaf()){
                Element K = Z;
                Code = "";
                while(K != X){ //here I want X to be reference the top of my huffman tree 
                    if(K == K.parent.left){
                        Code = Code+0;
                    }else{
                        Code = Code+1;
                    }
                    K = K.parent;
                }
            }Coder(Z.right);
        }
        return Code;
   }
}
```

So that X doesn't gets override while running `Coder` recursively. 
Nodes in this program is called `Element`. pq is part of another program that is a prioritycue with a heap structure.

This is the hole Encode Class

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;

public class Encode{
static int[] Freq=new int[256];
static PQ pq = new PQHeap(256);
static String Code;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Java\\testfilen.txt");
    Inputstream.Inputs(fis);

        for(int i=0; i<Freq.length; i++){
            pq.insert(new Element(Freq[i],new Integer(i)));
        }
            Element Z = Huffman();
            String K = Coder(Z);
            System.out.println(K);
}

public static Element Huffman(){
            int n = Freq.length;
    for(int i=1; i<=n-1; i++){
        Element z = new Element(0, 0);
        Element x=pq.extractMin();
        z.left=x;
        Element y=pq.extractMin();
        z.right=y;
        z.key = y.key+x.key;
        pq.insert(z);
    }
            return pq.extractMin();  
}

public static String Coder(Element Z){
        Element X = Z;
        if(Z != null){
            Coder(Z.left);
            if(Z.isleaf()){
                Element K = Z;
                Code = "";
                while(K != X){
                    if(K == K.parent.left){
                        Code = Code+0;
                    }else{
                        Code = Code+1;
                    }
                    K = K.parent;
                }
            }Coder(Z.right);
        }
        return Code;
   }
}
```

This is the `Element` class

```
public class Element {

public int key;
public Object data;
public Element parent;
public Element left;
public Element right;

public Element(int i, Object o){
this.key = i;
this.data = o;
    this.parent = null;
this.left=null;
this.right=null;
}
public boolean isleaf(){
    if(this.left == null && this.right == null){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This isn't clear. What is the problem here?

Comment: "So that X does not get overriden while running `Coder` recursively".. All that you need for that is to define `X` outside the `Coder` local scope (v.g., as an instance attribute). Which is the issue?

Comment: Also remember that a) it is not wise to compare objects with `==` or `!=` and b) Java naming conventions require variable names to start with lowercase.